# ListBox/ListBoxItem for BoundData Style Template Clarification WPF XAML

Tags: wpf, listbox, styles, controltemplate, listboxitem

How do I get a databound ListBox to accept a templated Style (from within my ResourceDictionary with the same name as the respective Style) for the ListBoxItem?

I see in Blend 4 that within the SimpleStyles ResourceDictionary file that the "SimpleListBoxItem" has property set to:

```
 d:IsControlPart="True"
```

but I am only able to use this when explicitly using the SimpleListBoxItem Style for xaml hard-coded ListBoxItems?

What makes sense to me is to apply the style to the ControlTemplate within the ListBox. I see the Control template within the listbox looks like:

```
ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            />
                    <ScrollViewer Margin="1" Style="{DynamicResource SimpleScrollViewer}" Focusable="false" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">

                        <!-- The StackPanel is used to display the children by setting IsItemsHost to be True -->
                        <StackPanel Margin="2" IsItemsHost="true"/>

                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Grid>
```

Is there a way to put one more nested "ItemsHost" Style template within that stackpanel? Maybe a DataTemplate?

Thanks in advance, let me know if further clarification is needed!

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do ... do you just mean to apply a template to the items, as in `ItemTemplate`?

Comment: @dbaseman : Ah, maybe that's it. I just want to apply a template to the child ListBoxItems, from within the ListBox Style (and 'Control') templates

Comment: So I take it you're using `<ListBox.Items>` and listing out the items in your XAML (as opposed to using `ItemsSource`)?

Comment: I'm not listing out the items, I'm binding ItemsSource property to my datacontext. Thanks for sticking with me, I realize how unclear that was.

Comment: Oh, ok ... then I think `ItemTemplate` is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How do I nest that within the Listbox Style (and within that, the given stackpanel)? (See the above code I'm using as reference.)

Comment: On second thought, I think you might want `ItemContainerStyle` -- see my answer below.  `ItemsPanel` is the container that presents the items (ie, by default I think it's a StackPanel inside a ScrollViewer), so it's not useful for styling the items themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options for applying a style to the items from within the `ListBox` style,  `ItemContainerStyle` and `ItemTemplate`.

1) `ItemContainerStyle` applies to the type `ListBoxItem` -- setting it styles the container of each item in the list:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" x:Key="SimpleListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green">
    <!-- etc -->
</Style>

<Style TargetType="ListBox" x:Key="ListBoxStyle">
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource SimpleListBoxItem}">
</Style>
```

2) The `ItemTemplate` property allows you to complete redefine the template for how each item is displayed, eg:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBox" x:Key="ListBoxStyle">
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="This is an item" />
                    <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding}" />
                <Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: @UB3571 I believe you can still use #1 in combination with #2.  Whatever template you define, it's still going to be wrapped in the `ListBoxItem` container, which is where you'd want to set the border.  Use the `ItemContainerStyle` to style it.